# TxReceipt Status:Fail TxHash: 0x3ff844d8ec7c7404cb0170c42f2eac1e0732e9dc8445b05cda9fe8d595431bde

Tags: transactions

I was hoping someone could help, I sent some ether to an ICO n I get Tx receipt status failed and when i look at the transaction on etherscan I get Value transfer did not complete most likely as a result of a revert opcode. I am new to this industry so i don't no where to start.Thanks 
TxHash: 0x3ff844d8ec7c7404cb0170c42f2eac1e0732e9dc8445b05cda9fe8d595431bde

even my previous transactions also failed with another ICO. TxHash:0x4948e49520187d14a7715365a53332cc7b9ce35b29ed3d8a6e5a98caaa070a9e

Do i have to do anything to stop these transaction, My MEW still showing the previous balance. Please help how to recover my ether.

Answer (score 1):

Your first transaction failed (likely due to some clause in the contract prohibiting you from buying tokens). It didn't run out of gas, but it was cancelled. All of your ether from that transaction are still yours to spend -- only the gas was consumed. There's no source code on Etherscan that I could use to identify how it failed in particular.

Your second transaction also failed. Those funds will also be returned automatically by the network because the transaction was cancelled.

[Your address](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa33605697bc05ee09cd671d80c49db69ff36bcd4) contains an ETH balance of 1.4 ETH. MyEtherWallet not showing your proper balance is a problem with that software -- not the network. For all intents and purposes, those transactions ate a tiny bit of gas but otherwise never happened.

If you want to troubleshoot what went wrong specifically, you need to talk to the ICOs that you're trying to participate in. The sale could not have started, be already over, or you might not meet other requirements to participate. We can't troubleshoot on a per contract level exactly *why* a failure happened, but the failed/cancelled status of the contract means that your funds weren't spent.